# Jagged mesh from orthographic view when data transfer is applied

Tags: modifiers

I have a clean surface and another surface with selected vertices which are making the surface uneven, so I apply the data transfer and from perspective view it looks clean, fixes up the topology but when seen from orthographic view, the jagged topology is still visible. I had the impression the data transfer takes the good mesh and fixes it up from the good chosen mesh.

[image]

Comment: No, this way it only takes shading of the object and transfers that shading on your uneven plane, because of that it looks like even plane from top views but from sides and in edit mode you will still see your old topology

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To transfer Vertices location from one mesh to another mesh with the same topology you can use **Shape Keys**. Just select object with final shape then target.

[image]

Go to *Properties Window > Data > Shape keys* and click plus icon to add *Base* key then under arrow (expand menu) choose **Join as Shapes**

[image]

Now when you change value to 1 vertices results in position of flat object.

[image]